# WIF10201: No valid key mapping found for securityToken: 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityToken' and issuer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wif, identityserver3

I'm using identity server v3 and the cert expired on the server. I generated a new cert in IIS, installed it in the cert store (trusted people, personal) and set the thumbprint in identity server. I installed the cert in the client application server (trusted people under certs) and updated the thumbprint in the client application. After reading the threads on the same issue I checked and double-checked the thumbprint and issuer name in identity server and client application - they both match in the identity server config and the client app config.

However I'm still getting this error in the client application, I've run out of things to try.

Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Maybe it's the rights to the private key on identity server side. Identity server probably runs under iis app pool that can not access the new private key.

Comment: Exactly my thoughts as well!